# Python Async decorator preserve typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

For the following file:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, TypeVar, cast

T = TypeVar('T')


def dec(args: Any) -> Callable[..., Awaitable[T]]:
    def dec2(f: Callable[..., Awaitable[T]]) -> Awaitable[T]:
        async def wrapper(*args:Any, **kwargs:Any) -> T:
            print(args)

            return cast(T, await f(*args, **kwargs))
        return cast(Awaitable[T], wrapper)
    return dec2


class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    async def fn(self) -> 'bool':
        pass

class B(A):
    @dec('hi')
    async def fn(self) -> 'bool':
        return True


class C(A):
    @dec('hi')
    async def fn(self) -> 'bool':
        return False
```

I am receiving the following mypy errors:

```
$ mypy typetest.py
typetest.py:24: error: Signature of "fn" incompatible with supertype "A"
typetest.py:30: error: Signature of "fn" incompatible with supertype "A"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How does the typing need to work in order to preserve the class signature and not receive the mypy error.

This is on python3.7 with mypy 0.790

Comment: Try using `-> bool` instead of `-> 'bool'`. Return types should not need quotations and that may interfere with the signature.

Comment: Quotes are valid. The only difference is that no name lookup will occur at runtime. Using `from __future__ import annotations` causes *all* annotations to be implicitly treated as string literals (and this will be the default in Python 3.10, I believe).

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: A function declaration `async def name(parameters) -> R:` creates an object of type `(parameters) -> Awaitable[R]`, not `Awaitable[R]`. This means the cast `cast(Awaitable[T], wrapper)` is wrong and should be omitted, and the various `Callable` return types must be adjusted as well.

---

A naive decorator to show the execution of an `async def` function (roughly `dec2`) would look like this:

```py
def show_call(f: Callable[..., Awaitable[T]]) -> Callable[..., Awaitable[T]]:
    async def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        print(f"Executing {f.__name__}")
        return await f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This *receives* an callable matching `async def` and *returns* a callable matching `async def`. In other words, it preserves the general type of "an `async` function".
Note that there is no `cast` needed.

Since the `Callable` argument was specified as `...`, the parameter information is lost. This can be fixed with [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) (Python 3.10 / [`typing_extensions`](https://github.com/python/typing/pull/774)) parameter variables, which are similar to type variables.

```py
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, TypeVar, ParamSpec

T = TypeVar('T')    # the callable/awaitable return type
P = ParamSpec('P')  # the callable parameters


def dec(message: Any) -> Callable[[Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]], Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]]:
    def dec2(f: Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]) -> Callable[P, Awaitable[T]]:
        async def wrapper(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
            print(message)
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return dec2
```

Comment: Mypy error: 
`The first argument to Callable must be a list of types or "..."`. Perhaps this is because of the https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8645 and your code is working.